# why schema_name(schema_id) is giving null in sys.types in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get the list of all the column names with type 'xml' along with their table name and schema names. I tried the following sql code :

```
select 
    OBJECT_NAME(b.object_id) as t1,
    b.name, a.name,
    OBJECT_NAME(a.schema_id, DB_ID('AdventureWorks2008R2')) as schema 
from 
    sys.types as a
inner join 
    sys.columns as b on a.user_type_id = b.user_type_id
where 
    a.name = 'xml'
```

Everything is fine except the schema name which is showing null. If I replace

```
OBJECT_NAME(a.schema_id,DB_ID('AdventureWorks2008R2'))
```

with

```
schema_name(schema_id)
```

I still get null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the schema from sys.tables. schema column in sys.types refers to the schema for the type itself. 
Try this:

```
select 
  OBJECT_NAME(b.object_id) as t1,
 b.name, 
 a.name,
SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)
from 
  sys.types as a
inner join 
  sys.columns as b on a.user_type_id = b.user_type_id
inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = b.object_id
where 
   a.name = 'xml'
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this confusion. I was thinking that schema from sys.tables and schema column in sys.types are the same

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(b.object_id)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SCHEMA_NAME` instead of `OBJECT_NAME`:

```
select 
    OBJECT_NAME(b.object_id) as t1,
    b.name, a.name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(a.schema_id)     -- use SCHEMA_NAME here
from 
    sys.types as a
inner join 
    sys.columns as b on a.user_type_id = b.user_type_id
where 
    a.name = 'xml'
```

Comment: still getting null values. for example schema id is showing 4 and if i do schema_name(schema_id) or schema_name(4) it gives me null.